# Adding content to tab dropdown menu html/bootstrap

Tags: html

With my HTML code I have created a dropdown menu within a tab.  I need to add content to those individual "tabs" in the dropdown menu.  I need help linking those together.

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active tab_class" style="background: #009933"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="background: #009933" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Teaching
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#a">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#b">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#c">Submenu 1-3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
<li class = "tab_class" style="background: #009933"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#research">Research</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

This is currently what my code looks like creating the tabs.  How can I correctly use classes and href to add content to each subtab within?  I am thinking I may not have correctly made subtab's active, but i'm also not sure how to go about doing that.  I am also using bootstrap within HTML and have that correctly imported.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You have a list of lists, a dropdown menu is an `<input>` element inside a `<form>`, it has nothing to do with lists.

Comment: @grochmal so what exactly would I have to change to make each submenu link to a difference page of information? change the <li>?